# Any good tutorials on the Build and Analyze feature in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, clang-static-analyzer

I would like to know  is there any tutorial to use xcode build and anylyse tool...

pls provide me links which points on it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? The analyzer does not run, or do you not understand the analyzer results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this apple link,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/220-Analyzing_Code/static_analysis.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006917-CH4-SW2

It will tell how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Jayahari V's link now seems to be broken, partly replaced by [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW1). If you still have the Xcode 3.2 documentation installed locally, searching for “Static Analysis in Xcode 3.2” gives a longer, though older, explanation.  The technical documentation is being worked on: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2011-March/013659.html.  In the meantime, use the source, e.g., https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/Checkers.td?view=co for a list of checkers and their help text.